# Using WebRTC to record from multiple media devices - resulting in distorted audio

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

After a user makes a device selection, I use the following to grab the stream from the device:

```
mediaDeviceScanner.getMediaByDeviceId = function (deviceId) {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { deviceId: { exact: deviceId } } });
}
```

This works great, even with multiple webcams connected.

The problem I'm encountering is that when the resulting stream is used within a `MediaRecorder`, the recorded audio is - occasionally - extremely distorted:

```
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaDevice.localStream(), getMediaRecorderOptions()); 
    // localStream is what the above method returns
```

Video recording is always fine.  Audio recording works fine with one device, however *sometimes* audio becomes highly distorted with multiple local devices connected.

I've tried to specify the audio device through `getUserMedia` with `deviceId / exact`, however this doesn't seem to be supported as of `Chrome 60.0`.

What might be causing this, and how can it be prevented?